# How to make all files non-executable recursively using find without affecting directories?

Tags: linux, find, command-line, flag

I need to strip the executable flag from all files within a certain directory and sub directories.  Right now I'm doing it with a 2 step process

```
find /dir/ -type f -exec chmod ugo-x {} \;
find /dir/ -type d -exec chmod ugo+rx {} \;
```

Is it possible to modify the first line so that I can strip exec flag from all non-directory files?  Since this needs to be done on a fairly regular basis across a lot of directories and files, I'd prefer not to use a bash script which would slow it down.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly doesn't your current command do properly? The `-type f` predicate already selects all files (or equivalently, all non-directory files, since anything that is a file cannot also be a directory).

Comment: @David: Sockets, FIFOs, symlinks, devices, etc.

Comment: @Ignacio: Yes, but the question was about files, not all those other non-file things.

Comment: @David: This is *nix. Everything is a file.

Comment: @Ignacio: Everything has a filesystem path, sure, but you can't always say that everything is actually a file. Some people do, but others use "file" in the sense of a regular file, i.e. something that would be matched by the `-type f` predicate to `find`. To me, the wording of this question strongly suggested the latter meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find ... '!' -type d ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize find had operators.  Are the single quotes necessary as I managed to get it to work without them?

Comment: It depends on your shell and its options. bash uses `!` in history expansion, so quoting it in the CLI is a good idea. You probably won't need it in a script though.

Comment: History expansion is not active in scripts, correct.